# ZSH not reading $PATH

Tags: shell-script, zsh, path

I have recently decided to move my personal scripts to a directory in my `$HOME`. I have included this directory in my `$PATH` variable but have had ZSH respond with "command not found" when attempting to run them. The following line is what I appended to `.xprofile`

```
PATH="$PATH:~/.local/share/";export PATH
```

I have a few scripts in `~/.local/share/` but haven't been able to execute them in ZSH, but in bash it works fine. I have tried adding the live above to my `.zshrc`, but that has not worked.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xprofile maybe

Comment: When you added that line to you `~/.zshrc` file, did your source the file or start a new shell before you tried to run the command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`~` is not a variable and does not behave like a variable.

Shells generally don't expand `~` when it is quoted.  You may use `$HOME` instead of `~` in any shell to make sure that you get the correct path to your home directory, without relying on the shell's special treatment of the tilde character (which is a shortcut mainly for use in interactive shells).

`$HOME` *does* behave like you'd expect a variable to behave, i.e. it gets expanded to the path of your home directory when it's quoted using double quotes.

Also note that it's unlikely that `PATH` is *not* already an environment variable. Exporting it is therefore not needed.

In the `zsh` shell, to add `~/.local/share` to the end of your command search path, you could also do

```
path+=~/.local/share
```

or

```
path+=$HOME/.local/share
```

The array variable `path` is *tied* to the scalar variable `PATH`, meaning that when you update the array `path` as above, the added element gets added to the end of the value `$PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

ZSH startup scripts are `~/.zshrc` and `~/.zshenv`. I usually put global environment variables like `PATH` in `~/.zshenv`.

It is possible that some other instructions in your startup scripts are overwriting/replacing your `PATH`. To see what is happening during zsh startup, run:

```
zsh -x 2>&1 </dev/null |grep PATH
```

Startup scripts do not affect shells that are already running. To get those updated:

- source the scripts e.g. `. ~/.zshenv`
- re-exec zsh (`exec zsh -l`)
- log out & log back in